# Alternetive to TableView

Tags: swift, ios8, custom-view

I'm doing an app that retrives data from a server and show it in a view using a tableview. 
What i'd really like to do is a view showing the content like images side by side. Just like this image:
[image: image from Untappd App]

Is there some native iOS component like TableView, spefic to this concept? What should be the better approach to get to this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use collection view if you want to show this kind of approach like as screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, take a look at [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/). It's sort of like a generalized tableview that can support a number of scrolling layout types.

For the mockup that you posted, you'll probably want to use a [`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/) configured with the cell size and horizontal/vertical spacing you need.